# ¿Alguien sabe como pasar variables enteras a strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

He usado esto pero me sale error en la consola

```
a = 23
b = 23
c = 21

simple = str(a, b, c)
print(simple)
```

El error es:

```
TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

Comment: Prodias ser mas claro en tu pregunta, edita el titulo con exactamente lo que quieres, y veo que es de python, no de javascript, asi que porfavor quita la tag. Asi sera mas sencillo ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Hola te refieres a esto ?

```
a = 23
b = 23
c= 21
simple = a,b,c
print(str(simple))
```

Comment: Sería más claro si explicaras que tipo de objeto es `simple` y dónde está el error del OP.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de 2 formas:

```
a = 23
b = 23
c = 21

simple = str(a), str(b), str(c)
print(simple)
```

Tendrás como resultado `('23', '23', '21')`, o sea, una tupla.

La otra forma es esta:

```
a = 23
b = 23
c = 21

print(str(a))
print(str(b))
print(str(c))
```

Y el resultado serían todos los números pasados a int de forma individual. También, en lugar de poner 3 print, puedes usar solo uno e ingresar las variables usando str en cada una: `print(str(a), str(b), str(c))`

El error en tu código está aquí:

```
simple = str(a, b, c)
print(simple)
```

Al poner str y meter esas 3 variables en los paréntesis, no estás transformando a las 3 en string, sino que solamente a la variable a. Por eso hay que poner str a cada una de las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando la funcion str incorrectamente,si utilizas los tres parametros se debe utilizar asi:

str(object, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')

puedes mirar mas de su uso en  la [documentación](http://.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq), en tu caso tendrias que usarla algo asi:

```
print (str(a)+str(b)+str(c))
```

O algo mas parecido a lo tuyo

```
simple = a,b,c
print(str(simple))
```